# How to stop ffmpeg and continue batch running

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, batch-processing

I have this small batch script. The purpose is to save small portion of our rtmp live stream

```
@echo off
echo Live Stream Cropper v0.1
echo **************************
echo video codec : libxh264
echo audio codec : mp3
echo **************************
echo Recording...
echo.

for /f "tokens=2 delims==" %%I in ('wmic os get localdatetime /format:list') do set datetime=%%I

set output=%datetime:~0,8%-%datetime:~8,4%

ffmpeg -i rtmp://my.streaming.path/public/appname -acodec mp3 -vcodec libx264  "X:\PATH\%output%.avi" -nostats -loglevel 0

echo.
echo "Recorded video is saved on X:\PATH\%output%.avi"
pause
```

The ffmpeg process is working as expected. My problem is after pressing CTRL + C to stop the process of ffmpeg, the echo command to show where the recorded file is saved is not executed.

How can I stop the ffmpeg process and then continue running the remaining of the script?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Some programs ignore the /wait option but you can try this. Essentially you will have to spawn ffmpeg into another environment and the main environment will wait for ffmpeg to finish before it continues.

```
START "FFMPEG" /WAIT ffmpeg -i rtmp://my.streaming.path/public/appname -acodec mp3 -vcodec libx264  "X:\PATH\%output%.avi" -nostats -loglevel 0
```

Give this a try as well.

```
cmd /c ffmpeg -i rtmp://my.streaming.path/public/appname -acodec mp3 -vcodec libx264  "X:\PATH\%output%.avi" -nostats -loglevel 0
```

Comment: I'm planning to show a spinner on the command prompt. is there a way that the main command prompt is the active window but CTRL + C will be sent to ffmpeg process? I tried your command and it works but the problem is ffmpeg terminal is on top and my spinner on the bat file will not be seen. hoping something that can hide the ffmpeg process and be able to stop it from the batch file command itself. if there is no option like that. I will have to settle with this. Thanks